# Independence of samples in behavioural study-can I use ANOVA/t tests?

Tags: anova, t-test, experiment-design, independence

I'm new to statistical analysis and I am using R to analyse the results of a small research project on tree rubbing behaviour in pigs.
I have three groups of pigs in three different pen sizes: small, medium and large.
I recorded the total duration of tree rubbing by two focal pigs in each group, and recorded each group three times (the same focal pigs each time).
I have taken the mean duration of tree rubbing for each recording session (averaging for the two focal pigs) in each group, then averaged the three means for each group to yield three means overall (one for each group) because each replicate is not independent. I would like to compare the three means to see if they vary according to pen size.

I know that it would have been better to increase the number of independent samples than to observe each group three times, but there were only three pens available for study at the time and I thought I could get a better estimate for the duration for each pen by making multiple observations and averaging.
I am having doubts about how to use ANOVA/ t tests (if I grouped the medium and large into one group, which I've been considering)/ other tests and have confused myself about the independence of the data points.

Is it legitimate to use these tests on my data? Can anyone suggest any alternatives if not?